# When did Kristoff Learn about the Cabin in Frozen?

Tags: plot-explanation, frozen

In the 2013 Disney movie *Frozen*, there is a scene where Kristoff is thrown out of Oaken's Trading Post into the snow after offending Oaken. As his reindeer, Sven, comes over to him Kristoff declares that he found them a "free" place to stay - a nearby log cabin. Here's the transcript from the [Transcripts Fandom](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Frozen) (emphasis mine):

> Kristoff: No, Sven, I didn't get your carrots. [Sven huffs his
>   disappointment] **But I did find us a place to sleep. [referring to the
>   dilapidated barn behind them] And it's free**. [inside the Oaken's
>   Trading Post Anna watches in shock as Oaken gets back behind the
>   counter]

At no point prior to this scene was the cabin mentioned - I don't believe it appeared on-screen either. While it's possible that Kristoff saw the cabin as Oaken threw him from the store, I don't think his dialog matches this scenario; something like "Hey look, that old cabin looks like a good place to sleep" would have made more sense. Instead his dialog shows that he already learned about the cabin but this didn't happen inside the store.

Kristoff could have noticed the cabin before going into the store, however not showing that scene makes the scene in question feel redundant to me.

**When did Kristoff learn about the unused cabin next to Oaken's Trading Post (and Sauna)?**

Comment: I'm sure he saw the cabin before he entered Oaken's Trading Post as it's near the entrance, but I don't think he decided to sleep there until Oaken threw him out. The cabin likely belongs to Oaken and spending the night there may have been Kristoff's way of "sticking it" to Oaken for dispatching him from the store. In Kristoff's dialogue to Sven, he is trying to hide the fact that their new lodging accommodations weren't secured ethically/legally, which Sven would have been unaware of having been outside while Kristoff was in the store.

Answer (score 2):

Kristoff spotted it after leaving the shop. Presumably his assumption is that he and Sven can use the barn for free as Oaken and his family are unlikely to come out into the cold.

> The hungry reindeer huffed in his face. Then **Kristoff turned his head
> and spotted something that made him brighten. There was a barn behind
> the trading post**—a warm place to spend the night.
>
> “But I did find us a place to sleep,” he added. “And it’s free.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Frozen: Book of the Film](https://frozen.fandom.com/wiki/Frozen:_Book_of_the_Film)</sup></sub>

This matches up with [the Final Shooting Draft screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Frozen-(Disney).html) where he's described as *"see[ing] something"*

> Oaken slams the door. Kristoff sits up. His reindeer, Sven, canters over, snorts, and nudges him, expectantly.
>
> **KRISTOFF:** *No Sven, I didn't get your carrots.*
>
> Sven huffs in his face. Kristoff turns away and sees something. He points to a dilapidated barn.
>
> **KRISTOFF** (CONT'D): But I did find us a place to sleep. And it's free.